# How to make a function wait for another function to finish excecution in angular2

Tags: angular, observable

I need to get the user input to continue excecution of a functoion , how can i make the function wait for   waitForUserInput().

if i can solve this using observables can anyone help me to integrate observables to a simple functiuon defined inside components

this is where iam stuck

```
 myFunction(){
    doSomeOperation();
    result=waitForUserInput(); // Here a prompt will be shown, 
    if(result==1)
    {
    operation1();
    }
    else if(result==2)
    {
    operation2();
    }
    else if(result==3)
    {
    operation3();
    }
 }
// This function will show a prompt and user can input values    
 waitForUserInput(){ 
    showUserInputPrompt();
    if(input==someValue1)
    {
    return 1;
    }
    else if(input==someValue2)
    {
    return 2;
    }
    else if(input==someValue3)
    {
    return 3;
    }
 }
```

here i need to wait until waitForUserInput() is completed before proceeding

Comment: Your first function calls `waitForUserInput()` repeatedly; if I want option 3 I have to enter 3 three times.

Comment: purpose was to convey the idea

Comment: You haven't really succeeded in that, either!

Comment: ok thank you for your support, i dont need it anymore

Comment: Then I'd suggest you just delete the question. No point leaving it around if the requirement no longer exists.

Comment: i specifically said your support .. yours

Comment: Then I would suggest that you need to improve both your use of "it" (as you've now confused both people who interacted with this post with... it) and your feedback (as that's neither specific nor kind). You don't get to tell people when they can and can't use comments; if you didn't want input, don't post on a public, community-moderated site.

Comment: sorry about that, i am stuck in a way i cant even explain.i am very sorry about the way i responded

Comment: I understand your frustration. Could you show a [mcve] of the *current* implementation to demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve? That might be more fruitful than asking about a specific solution (see e.g. http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. You can't halt a function in the browser. 
In the browser there is only one UI thread. If you halt it, nothing will happen anymore in your application, therefore it's not supported at all.

You need to choose a different strategy to get what you want to accomplish.

Comment: is there a way i can make it observable ?

Comment: waitForUserInput()

Comment: I don't get what you think that buys you. Please change your question and describe what the actual problem is that you try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If your called function allows for callback you can do something like this=>

this.instance.saveEditData().done(this.CustomSave);

function CustomSave() {
}

CustomSave is the parent and I was calling saveEditData inside it. But changed the logic to call it only when saveEditData is done.